# Is there any way to bind a Node to the midpoint of a Line?

Tags: java, javafx

What I need to do is draw a Text in the middle of a Line. This is what I originally came up with:

```
Text tWeight = new Text(Integer.toString(e.getWeight()));
tWeight.setX((e.getEdge().getStartX() + e.getEdge().getEndX()) / 2);
tWeight.setY((e.getEdge().getStartY() + e.getEdge().getEndY()) / 2);
```

Where `e.getEdge()` returns a Line.
The problem is that the Line returned also has a bind between two Nodes, so when I try to get its position it returns the coordinates of the upper left corner of the Pane where the Line exists. 
Is there any way (or trick) to make this work from the start?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the [`javafx.beans.binding`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/package-summary.html) package. The `Bindings` class provides a static API while the `XXXExpression` classes provide a fluent API. Note the class hierarchies of the standard property implementations (e.g. [`DoubleProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/DoubleProperty.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DoubleExpression`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleExpression.html) (supertype of `DoubleProperty`) provides the `add(ObservableNumberValue)` and `multiply(double)` methods. You can use those to create an expression for `(startX+endX)*0.5` (or equivalent for y):

```
Line l = e.getEdge();
tWeight.xProperty().bind(l.startXProperty().add(l.endXProperty()).multiply(0.5));
tWeight.yProperty().bind(l.startYProperty().add(l.endYProperty()).multiply(0.5));
```